# site inaccesible when i run a vhost

Tags: server, apache2

I've been trying for 2 days to just run my vhost that worked perfectly until now. I searched without being able to find the solution.The site is already enabled. Here is the error i got:
This site is inaccessible project.local does not allow the connection.
Do a Google search on local project.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Here are my configuration files:

```
projet.conf
```

```
ServerName projet.local
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot "/home/malik/WCS"
<Directory "/home/malik/WCS" >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

in ect/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   projet.local
```

/var/log/apache2/access.log.1:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2018:15:16:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 771 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.67 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2018:17:28:13 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 771
```

error.log.1 :

```
[Wed Dec 19 09:58:34.636654 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1436] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 19 09:58:34.636691 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1436] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Dec 20 02:22:52.333222 2018] [core:warn] [pid 1436] AH00045: child process 4808 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Dec 20 02:22:52.448879 2018] [core:warn] [pid 1436] AH00045: child process 4809 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Dec 20 02:22:52.448895 2018] [core:warn] [pid 1436] AH00045: child process 4810 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Dec 20 02:22:52.448900 2018] [core:warn] [pid 1436] AH00045: child process 4811 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Dec 20 02:22:52.448904 2018] [core:warn] [pid 1436] AH00045: child process 4812 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
[Thu Dec 20 02:22:53.465018 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1436] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded
Cannot load Xdebug - it was already loaded

$ sudo netstat -plnt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1169/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:63342         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4608/java       
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2182/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4456/cupsd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6942          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4608/java       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      4456/cupsd   

$ apachectl -S
[Thu Jan 03 17:49:33.928029 2019] [so:warn] [pid 5785] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:

127.0.0.1:80           is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost blog.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/blog.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost hph.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hph.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost librairie.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/librairie.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost projet.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/projet.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost symfony.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/symfony.conf:1)
127.0.1.1:80           cornac.local (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cornac.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

sudo systemctl start apache2.service

systemctl status apache2.service

apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since jeu. 2019-01-03 21:30:34 CET; 2min 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 13298 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 13274 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

janv. 03 21:30:20 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
janv. 03 21:30:27 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]: [Thu Jan 03 21:30:27.211423 2019] [so:warn] [pid 13291] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
janv. 03 21:30:32 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]: [Thu Jan 03 21:30:32.218467 2019] [core:error] [pid 13291] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve ho
janv. 03 21:30:32 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerN
janv. 03 21:30:34 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
janv. 03 21:30:34 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]: Action 'start' failed.
janv. 03 21:30:34 malik-X751LJ apache2[13274]: The Apache error log may have more information.
janv. 03 21:30:34 malik-X751LJ apache2[13298]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
janv. 03 21:30:34 malik-X751LJ apache2[13298]:  *
janv. 03 21:30:34 malik-X751LJ systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.

Any help would be appreciate, Thanks

Comment: Note that if you only have a single VHOST online you will still get a connection - CONNECTION REFUSED usually indicates Apache is not listening properly.

Comment: thanks for your return. I have several vhosts that worked until now. I just put this one as an example. I really do not understand why nothing works now

Comment: Connection Refused usually means you have Apache problems somewhere.  Confirm that Apache is listening by checking `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` to see if Apache is even listening on port 80.

Comment: what is the expected result of this order? because nothing is happening

Comment: i got this when i run sudo service apache2 status

Comment: apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)

Comment: if you get any output then something's listening on POrt 80.  If you got none, then your Apache is just not working.  Check the logs for details (and add logs to your question as an edit)

Comment: the var/log/apache2/access.log displays nothing, an empty file.. I edit the access.log.1 file but i m still perplexed about this issue

Comment: See `/var/log/apache2/error.log` instead.

Comment: the error.log is empty too. I edit error.log.1

Comment: Your apache isn't running and its last signs of life are from two weeks ago according to the error.log, and the last access is 3 months ago. I suggest running a syntax check on your config files. Please add the output of `apachectl -S` (no sudo needed) to your post.

Comment: @PerlDuck yes its seems that my apache doesn't work. I still have not found the solution. I edit the output of sudo netstat -plnt and apachectl -S. Thanks for your reply

Comment: What happens when you start it `sudo systemctl start apache2.service`?

Comment: i think it loads the apache2.service . I edit the outputs

Answer (score 0):

Your `ServerName` parameter is set to `projet.local` when you really want it to be `project.local`.

Change that, save, reload apache2 (`sudo systemctl reload apache2`) and try again.

You will also need to update your `/etc/hosts` (note: `etc` and not `ect` also) file as it's spelt wrong in there too.

Comment: hank you jamie but project or project I do not think the problem is there. It used to work like any other vhost I created. I admit that I really do not see where this issue comes from

Comment: @Touco Your error message says `This site is inaccessible project.local` but it is configured as `projet.local` (without the `c`.

Comment: @PerlDuck it's just because of the translation, i am french. The server name is projet.local without the c

Comment: @Touco try to run `echo Listen 80 >> /etc/apache2/ports.conf` and stop, disable, enable, start your apache2!!

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri may i add echo listen 80 in the ports.conf file? i m not sure to understand what to do

Comment: @Touco yap, try to add `Listen 80` in ports.conf file

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri  i already have this line in the ports.conf. I think there is a crash in apache. right now when i start my computer i always have this error apache2 crashed with sigsegv in zend_startup. Maybe I should reinstall apache